# jasper report displaying values based on boolean

Tags: java, layout, jasper-reports, boolean, report

what is the best way to implement fields that will either be empty or contain a value depending on a boolean value being passed from the java end ot the jrxml code.
ideally i want to display a value if there is a value, if it is null i dont want anything being displayed. what im looking for is what components are needed.

```
  after the question mark, i take i should place what i want to display if "whatever" is true.
 <textFieldExpression class="java.math.BigDecimal"> <[CDATA[$P{whatever}.equalsIgnoreCase("TRUE")?></textFieldExpression>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the "Blank When Null" property.

```
<textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
```